# Android Application not installable from market

Tags: android, google-play

I've written an android app and have been testing it on my Galaxy S2 and an Novo 7 Paladin which is based on a MIPS architecture.  Everything works fine on both, but when I put the app on the market the Novo 7 says it's not compatible.  Is there something I need to do to the apk to allow it to run on the MIPS architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Device Availability dialog in your Developer Console. Your manifest file probably contains requirements that are excluding that device.

See:
https://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=it&ctx=go&answer=1286017

HTH,
Daniele